# Scala 2D array sorting by specified column

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, matrix

Given any 2D array, e.g,

```
val in = Array( Array(59, 45, 32), 
                Array(20, 88, 5), 
                Array(49, 72, 89))
```

would like to sort it by the third column, so that

```
val out = Array( Array(20, 88, 5),
                 Array(59, 45, 32),                       
                 Array(49, 72, 89))
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, but will fail if your arrays are of size less than 3:

```
scala> in.sortBy(_(2))
```

Output:

```
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(20, 88, 5), Array(59, 45, 32), Array(49, 72, 89))
```

You may also make this fail-safe like this:

```
in.sortBy {
  case arr @ Array(_) if arr.size >= 3 => arr(2)
  case arr => Int.MaxValue // or any other value. Using MaxValue will make the invalid arrays be last ones
}
```

Comment: Your second solution can write as `scala> in.sortBy { case Array(_, _, x, _*) => x; case _ => Int.MaxValue }`

Comment: Thanks. I think there are several ways to do the same thing and I just picked the first one I came to :)

Answer (score 1):

```
in.sortWith(_(2) < _(2))
```

will sort the array, using the third element of the Array.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is Array[Array[Int]], you just need to use `yourArray.sortBy(_(3))`. 3 is your field index, which you want to order according to this column.

But, if your array is not Array[Array[Int]], you can't use sortBy directly. You'd better to use Sorting which is imported from `scala.util.Sorting`

Here is my code.

```
import scala.util.Sorting

Sorting.quickSort(yourArray)(new Ordering[Array[String]] {
  def compare(x: Array[String], y: Array[String]) = {
    x(3) compare y(3)
  }
})
```

My array is Array[Array[String]], x(3) is one field which you want to compare. Of course, if you want to reverse sorting, you just need to use `y(3) compare x(3)` to replace `x(3) compare y(3)`.

If your array is other type, you just need to use your type to replace `Array[String]`